# Remapping only 1 key to another

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, remapping

I rarely use '[`^`](http://unicode-table.com/en/005E/)' ([Shift+6](http://unicode-table.com/en/005E/) or [Unicode U+005E](http://unicode-table.com/en/005E/)) and use '[`⁓`](http://unicode-table.com/en/2053/)' ([Unicode U+2053](http://unicode-table.com/en/2053/)) all the time as part of my signature on emails and so forth.

I realize the *Swung Dash* (`⁓`) and *Tilde* (`~`) are very similar, I just find the longer one more aesthetically pleasing for signatures and stuff like that.

Is there a way I can remap `^` to `⁓` ?
Or when remapping keys is it all or nothing?

Any advice is welcomed!

⁓ Ev

PS ⁓ See, there it is.  Twice.  In the signature and PS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one idea:

1. Define a compose key. You do that in *System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Typing*.
2. Create the file `~/.XCompose` with this contents:

   ```
   include "%L"
   <Multi_key> <U007E> <U007E> : "⁓" U2053 # SWUNG DASH
   ```

That way (at next login) typing **<Compose> + ~ + ~** will result in ⁓.

Not exactly what you asked for, but maybe you still want to consider it.

Comment: In Mint's Keyboard Shortcuts settings via Control Center, all I have are the following categories:

 - Sound
 - Desktop
 - Accessibility
 - Window Management

And then when I go to enter a new one by pressing the ' + ADD ' button, I'm given an option to input a new name and a command.

So, could you please tell me what I should title the command?  I'm thinking of naming it `^ ▶ ⁓` (that is if it allows it.  What's should I put into the empty Command box?

Thanks :)

Comment: @Evan: AFAIK you can't use a shortcut to change the behavior of a key. The approach I suggested in my answer is to make use of a compose key to type the desired character, and I showed how you define it in Ubuntu. Don't know how you define a compose key in Mint. OTOH, questions about Mint are off topic here.

Comment: Cool, thanks, dude.  Just to clarify,  by creating this, every time I type "~~" it'll autocorrect to "⁓".  Is that right?  That's perfect, thanks! :)

Comment: @Evan: Not every time; only when you type <Compose> first.